# How to update Oracle DB version from 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.2.0?

Tags: database, oracle

I have installed Oracle Database `11.2.0.1.0` in my Windows 10 desktop PC with the installation files from official site [link](https://www.oracle.com/kr/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html).

Is it possible to update this to `11.2.0.2.0` ?

I'm asking this because our staging server uses `11.2.0.2.0` so I'd like to match the version.

Thanks.

Comment: You can only download the patch releases if you have a support contract. But why bother with 11.x anyway? It's deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you have an Oracle support account you can download a CPU to upgrade. But if you don't, I would suggest to follow this link : http://mydbspace.com/?p=104 ( although is Linux, the operative is more or less the same )

It explains very well the steps, nevertheless, are you aware that 11g is already unsupported. You should try to use a newer version.

Rergards

Comment: Actually Oracle database 11.2.0.x is still supported in sustaining support stage. Yes  Premier support and extended support are no more available for 11.2 releases. But all old Oracle versions are still supported in sustaining level support according to https://www.oracle.com/support/lifetime-support/.

Comment: Obviously, when I said unsupported perhaps I did not use the right term. What I meant is that once a version is deprecated and leaves the normal support program, you will not get any patch unless you are paying premium extended support. My point is that given that you are going to make an effort to upgrade, do it to a newer version.